# TypeError for module in EC2 - Works fine on my PC

Tags: python, string, amazon-ec2, operators, typeerror

I'm using the instabot_py module to automate some social media processes. This involves checking whether variables are above a certain value (i.e. if followers > 0 then ). It works fine on my PC both through command line and Eclipse but a TypeError is thrown when I run it on my EC2.

I've tried updating python versions and skirting around these checks but they are process critical. The default value of self.bot.follow_time is 0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/instabot-py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/instabot_py/__main__.py", line 252, in main
    bot.mainloop()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/instabot_py/instabot.py", line 756, in mainloop
    self.new_auto_mod_unfollow()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/instabot_py/instabot.py", line 899, in new_auto_mod_unfollow
    user = self.persistence.get_username_to_unfollow_random()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/instabot_py/persistence/sql.py", line 95, in get_username_to_unfollow_random
    if self.bot.follow_time > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Expecting no error messages and the logic to run as expected